# how to query exact integer data in redis

Tags: redis, node-redis

I have redis data like this

```
HMSET cars:1 make Ferrari model 458 color red topSpeed 202
HMSET cars:2 make Porsche model 555 color yellow topSpeed 300

ZADD topSpeed 202 1
ZADD topSpeed 300 2
```

Range Query : `ZRANGEBYSCORE topSpeed 200 300`

So how to query **exact** topSpeed like 202 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE topSpeed 202 202
```

From [the documentation](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore):

> Returns all the elements in the sorted set at key with a score between min and max ***(including elements with score equal to min or max)***.